# Fix dependencies pandas python3

Tags: python3, numpy, pandas

Today I installed another package via

```
pip3 install seaborn
```

after doing so my pandas package seems to be broken and I have no idea how to fix it. I tried to uninstall and reinstall pandas, numpy and seaborn but always get the same error.

```
"Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get missing required dependency error messages if you install the Pandas, Numpy and Seaborn packages from the default Ubuntu repositories. To install the Python 3 versions of Pandas, Numpy and Seaborn in Ubuntu 16.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-pandas python3-numpy python3-seaborn
```

To install the Python 3 versions of Pandas and Numpy in Ubuntu 14.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-pandas python3-numpy
```

To install Seaborn in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip    
python3 -m pip install --user seaborn
```

It seems like a waste of time to install Seaborn with pip in Ubuntu 14.04, because Ubuntu 14.04 will reach End of Life in another two months. If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 this would be a good time to  think about upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Thanks so much that solved my question. I just uninstalled and deleted the dependency folder and everything work without any flaws.