# How to fix native python/pandas problem: TypeError: descriptor '__subclasses__' of 'type' object needs an argument

Tags: 16.04, python, pandas

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.6 and after I install a few python packages (listed below), and enter Python3 and type `import pandas`, I get this error:

```
myBashPrompt:~$ python3 
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/anon/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "/home/anon/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pandas.core.arrays.integer import (
  File "/home/anon/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .array_ import array  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/anon/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/array_.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.common import (
  File "/home/anon/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/common.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes import (
  File "/home/anon/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/dtypes.py", line 53, in <module>
    class Registry:
  File "/home/anon/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/dtypes.py", line 84, in Registry
    self, dtype: Union[Type[ExtensionDtype], str]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 552, in __getitem__
    dict(self.__dict__), parameters, _root=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in __new__
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in <genexpr>
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 1077, in __subclasscheck__
    if super().__subclasscheck__(cls):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/abc.py", line 225, in __subclasscheck__
    for scls in cls.__subclasses__():
TypeError: descriptor '__subclasses__' of 'type' object needs an argument
```

How can I fix this or avoid this error?
The last time I posted this, I thought it was because I upgraded Ubuntu. Upgrading is not the problem. These are the other packages I installed.

```
pip3 install pygame
pip3 install pymunk
pip3 install numpy
pip3 install matplotlib==3.0.3 #installed older version because new version requires python3.6
pip3 install scipy
pip3 install PyQt5
sudo pip3 install pyqtgraph
sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin
pip3 install cntk
pip3 install h5py
sudo pip3 install keras
pip3 install visvis --user
pip3 install seaborn --user
pip3 install pandas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out [the solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1122198/532995) is to install from `apt`.

```
sudo apt install python3-pandas python3-numpy python3-seaborn
```

After which there may be problems with `pip3`, which can be solved [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59048653/6552114).